# Span grid items to the full width of the CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-grid

How do I use `display:grid` so it only targets `.entry` or `.post` elements and excludes the archive title and pagination?

(`archive-description` and the `pagination` to span the full width of the content div)

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<main class="content">

  <div class="archive-description">Archive Title</div>

  <article class="post entry">This is a post</article>

  <article class="post entry">This is a post</article>

  <article class="post entry">This is a post</article>

  <li class="pagination">Previous & Next Entry</li>

</main>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/haymanpl/rb0hqb7g/2/

Comment: ...but basically... **you can't** The layout of those elements will be affected by the Grid properties on the parent. You can't opt *out* a a Grid by class.

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what it is this is *supposed* to look like. Or just take that div out of the Grid entirely - https://jsfiddle.net/nkkmau2x/

Comment: @Dev do you want to have the `archive-description` and the `pagination` to span the grid columns?

Comment: @kukkuz full width of the content div

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can *span* the `archive-description` and `pagination` across the columns of the grid by using `grid-column: span 3`.

See demo below - added borders for illustration (also made the `li` to `div` for valid markup):

```css
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.archive-description, .pagination {
  grid-column: span 3;
  text-align: center;
}
main > * {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<main class="content">
  <div class="archive-description">Archive Title</div>
  <article class="post entry">This is a post</article>
  <article class="post entry">This is a post</article>
  <article class="post entry">This is a post</article>
  <div class="pagination">Previous & Next Entry</div>
</main>
```

Comment: kukkuz Thanks but doesn't work on templates with sidebar.